# Dask Dataframe groupby has no len()

Tags: python, dataframe, dask

If you have a groupby object based on a dask dataframe why does `len(<groupby object>)` return an error?  (bug or feature)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just hasn't been implemented.  You might want to raise an issue (or better yet, a pull request).  Pragmatically I would just call `nunique` on your grouping object

#### Before

```
g = df.groupby(df.x + df.y)
result = len(g)
```

#### After

```
result = (df.x + df.y).nunique()
```

Operationally this is nicer because it can be lazy (the result of `len` in Python must be a concrete integer) and because you can choose the `nunique_approx` variant, which will be far faster.